# How to access application property in org.quartz.Job class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have created a spring boot application to implement Quartz scheduler. In Job class, I want to use some property from application.properties. How to inject that?

When I am trying to use it using value annotation, getting null.

Here is my code

Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SchedulerApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public Scheduler scheduler() {

        Scheduler scheduler = null;
        try {

            SchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();


        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scheduler;

    }

}
```

Job Class:

```
@Component
public class ScheduleJob implements org.quartz.Job {

    @Value("${ijobs.service.url}")
    public String ijobsUrl;

    public ScheduleJob() {

    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        String jobName = null;
        System.out.println("ijobsUrl--->"+ijobsUrl);
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> try to use this @Order on Job class

```
  @Component
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
    public class ScheduleJob implements org.quartz.Job {

        @Value("${ijobs.service.url}")
        public String ijobsUrl;

        public ScheduleJob() {

        }

        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
            String jobName = null;
            System.out.println("ijobsUrl--->"+ijobsUrl);
            } 

  }
```

Comment: ijobsUrl--->null
getting null :(

Comment: configured via quartz.properties on the classpath

Comment: ijobs.service.url  ="/something"            add that property to your quartz.properties                                                 
 Properties p = new Properties();
p.load("/resources/quartz.properties"); // path to your properties file
System.out.println(p.getProperty("ijobs.service.url");

Comment: and just see the details here,.....   http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/